# get a list of files with winrar command line

Tags: command-line, winrar

I want to get a list of files and preferably uncompressed file size via winrar command line. How do i do this? and how do i do this with a password? From the doc it looks like i use -pPASSWORD

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Winrar comes with Rar.exe command-line tool. You could use it in the following format:

Rar.exe l -pPASSWORD archive.rar

Comment: Great :D I had no idea what that meant in the documentation. But i know this could be done! :)

Answer (score 4):

The commands `l` (lower L) and `lb` (LB) are available in rar.exe and unrar.exe (but not in Winrar.exe)

The command `l` lists a lot of other informations beside the filename (compression-rate, date, ...) if you just need the filenames then use `lb` instead of `l`:

```
unrar.exe lb -pPASSWORD archive.rar >files.txt
```