# Powershell, filtering WinRar output

Tags: powershell

I'm running the following code in powershell

```
$list=C:\"Program Files (x86)"\WinRAR\unRAR.exe v -v $absolutePath
$list
```

And this is my output:

```
Archivo C:\Users\Maxi\Desktop\pruebaz\pruebaz.rar

Ruta/Comentario
                  Tamaño   Compresión  Fecha   Hora     Atrib     CRC   Métod-Ver-
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 pruebaz\chu.jpg
                 63171    61575  97% 19-09-13 17:10  .....A.   B5F99319 m3b 2.9
 pruebaz\nada\hola\cruci.jpg
                 55306    54496  98% 16-11-13 02:03  .....A.   87537917 m3b 2.9
 pruebaz\nada\hola
                     0        0   0% 15-07-14 23:01  .D.....   00000000 m0  2.0
 pruebaz\nada
                     0        0   0% 15-07-14 23:01  .D.....   00000000 m0  2.0
 pruebaz
                     0        0   0% 15-07-14 23:01  .D.....   00000000 m0  2.0
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    5           118477   116071  97%
```

I need help filtering this to get the following:

```
pruebaz\chu.jpg             
pruebaz\nada\hola\cruci.jpg      
pruebaz\nada\hola               
pruebaz\nada                
pruebaz
```

Thanks.

Comment: Try using the [`unrar.exe lb pruebaz.rar`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14316921/21567). It seems that gives you a plain file list.

Comment: this gives me:
`chu.jpg
cruci.jpg
hola
nada
pruebaz`
but not the path, just a list of things inside the rar file. I need a list of things in the rar file, but with it's corresponding path

Comment: Too bad. I haven't the tools at hand, so I cannot play around with them myself. My point was: try to find a command line option that produces a simpler (to parse) output. I figured `lb` could be it.

Comment: Thanks, I will keep playing around with it.

Comment: @MaximilianoSchultheis: `unrar.exe lb` gave me an output like `directory directory\file` with each item listed in a separate line, using unRAR 5.00. Are you seeing a different thing? Are you using a different version maybe?

Comment: Oh yes, I'm using version 3.93. I'll try again after upgrading, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this answers your question, or what the output type is for the unrar command, but you could try to pipe `$list` into `Get-Member`

`$list | Get-Member`

If the output of that gives you a Member Type of Property you can access that directly with

`$list.PropertyName`

For example with `Get-ChildItem` you can

$list = Get-ChildItem
$list | Get-Member

Giving the following partial output.

[image]

And then use

`$list.FullName`

Comment: $list | get-member gives me MemberType of method, not property

Comment: whats the complete output?

Comment: The output type of `unrar.exe` is plain text - not an object. So this will not work.

Comment: that is what I thougt, I need some help filtering it with some regex-type of method, but I'm having a hard time figuring it out